# Retrieve a list of non associated (free) Elastic IPs that have already been allocated through terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, elastic-ip

I want to use the `aws_eip` `terraform` data [source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/eip) to retrieve a list of the Elastic IPs already allocated in my account; I want those that are free, i.e. they have not been associated with any resource.

Here is what I did:

```
data "aws_eip" "free_elastic_ips" {
  filter {
    name   = "association-id"
    values = ["null"]
  }
}
```

The problem is that this errors out:

```
│ Error: no matching EC2 EIP found
│
│   with data.aws_eip.free_elastic_ips,
│   on main.tf line 38, in data "aws_eip" "free_elastic_ips":
│   38: data "aws_eip" "free_elastic_ips" {
│
```

despite the fact that I have free Elastic IPs in my org.

Here is the output of `aws ec2 describe-addresses` for one such IP (values scrambled intentionally)

```json
        {
            "PublicIp": "13.24.111.20",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-0d7ffe3iktk47aafkc",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "PublicIpv4Pool": "amazon",
            "NetworkBorderGroup": "us-east-1"
        },
```

e.g.

[image]

(and this is just one of them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping `null` in double quotes means you are asking it to search for Elastic IPs where the actual association ID is the literal string "null" as in lower case n u l l  . Try removing the quotes `values = [null]` or perhaps try an empty values list `values = []`.