# Getting errors while trying to find unnassociated EIPs with terraform data source for aws_eips

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, elastic-ip

I am using a terraform data source for aws_eip target the usage of specific EIPs in my account that are currently unused.
I have some other filters, e.g to get ones from a specific range and ones that have a specific tag - these are all working fine.

As soon as I add the filter to check for EIPs that aren't currently associated with anything, I get no results. Using the same filter on the aws console returns all the unused EIPs

I've tried the following:

```
  filter {
    name = "instance-id"
    values = []
  }
```

```
  filter {
    name = "instance-id"
    values = [""]
  }
```

```
  filter {
    name = "association-id"
    values = []
  }
```

```
  filter {
    name = "association-id"
    values = [""]
  }
```

And they all result in:
Error: no matching EC2 EIP found

Comment: what's the goal? are you trying to create a pool of unused EIPs? quite interesting this [Thread](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/list-free-aws-elastic-ips-through-terraform/53026) in Hashicorp!

Comment: The goal is to use an eip from a block that has been allocated to my account. Searching for an eip within this range (works) and one that is unused (doesn't work).

Comment: getting the same result, despite I followed the the recommendation by @mark-b in [Retrieve a list of non associated (free) Elastic IPs that have already been allocated through terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081197/retrieve-a-list-of-non-associated-free-elastic-ips-that-have-already-been-allo)

Comment: Appreciate your attempts, I followed the suggestion from that thread also.